# how to export a foxpro cursor to a CSV file?

Tags: database, export-to-excel, export-to-csv, visual-foxpro

In visual foxpro, i have a cursor which is the result of a sql query, when i export the content of that cursor to a csv file using the statement :

```
 COPY TO "c:\test.csv" type DELIMITED
```

all data is messed up, i do not pecify any delimiter so basically foxpro takes the default, which is every column in that cursor. bow when i run the same command to an xls file, and then convert it to a csv file...it works very well:

```
     COPY TO "c:\test.xls" type XL5
```

anyone has had such issue, any one still using foxpro and doing stuff like those?

Comment: In what way is the output "messed up"?  Can you post a sample?  What is the structure of the cursor?

Comment: thanks for your answer, dates are blank, all numerical values to 0 (except some...why i don't know) and also skipping records(some times). so i think there are some bugs haven't been fixed in this version (7 old version) and which we can't do anything about, unless you have a magic solution that will save my life :)

Comment: Odd.  I don't have version 7 to try, only VFP 9 SP2, and it works fine for me.

Comment: Does your DBF data have commas in any fields which will screw up the output ?

Comment: Alan, no no commas just dates and integers, doubles... that was the first thing i've checked, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I never liked the built-in DBF to CSV converters.  They always seemed to do things I did not want them to do.   So I just wrote my own.  Here is some code to get you started.

```
LOCAL lnFields

SELECT DBF
lnFieldCount = AFIELDS(laFields)
lnHandle = FOPEN("filename.csv", 1)
ASSERT lnHandle > 0 MESSAGE "Unable to create CSV file"

SCAN
    lcRow = ""
    FOR lnFields = 1 TO lnFieldCount
    IF INLIST(laFields[lnFields,2], 'C', 'M')
            lcRow = lcRow + IIF(EMPTY(lcRow), "", ",") + '"' + ;
                            STRTRAN(EVALUATE(laFields[lnFields,1]),'"', '""') + '"'
        ELSE
            lcRow = lcRow + IIF(EMPTY(lcRow), "", ",") + ;
                            TRANSFORM(EVALUATE(laFields[lnFields,1]))
        ENDIF
    ENDFOR

    FWRITE(lnHandle, lcRow)
ENDSCAN
FCLOSE(lnHandle)
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using TYPE CSV in the COPY TO command?

Comment: thanks, CSV and DELIMITED give the same result. also just wondering if execution time makes a difference ? when debugging (F8) or just executing the query alone and executing the COPY command thru the command window...the results are completely different from when the whole program is running, thou the program is "very simple" : grab data process and copy...

Comment: That you're getting different results when stepping through the code or running it without interruption is very odd. Have you tried using a BROWSE just before the COPY TO to exactly what the source data is? Hmm, actually, that idea makes me wonder whether there's a work area issue; that is, are you sure the right work area is selected before you issue COPY TO.